# How to do data fitting to find the distribution of given data

Tags: statistics, distribution, data-fitting, gamma-distribution

I need to do data fitting to find the distribution of a given data.

I need to find the pdf function of the distribution.

I can use data fitting functions in matlab and python.

It looks like a truncated gamma.

But, how to find the parameters of the distribution ?

What if the data cannot fit the  truncated gamma well ?

The QQ-plot (qunatile-quantile) show that it is not a good fit for truncated
gamma.

How to find the distribution parameters such as alpha (shape), beta (scale) 
for the truncated gamma ?

If data fitting cannot work here, what other methods I can use for that ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see `fit` function in [`sccipy.stats.gamma`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html#scipy.stats.gamma). if you want to try other distributions [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#continuous-distributions) is a list of distributions supported by scipy and each should have a `fit` function

Answer (score 1):

Check out [allfitdist](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2012/02/10/finding-the-best/) in Matlab.

Alternatively, consider specialty packages such as ExpertFit or EasyFit. The JMP statistical software also has a fairly easy to use distribution fitting option.  All of these will evaluate goodness-of-fit criteria such as [Cramer-von Mises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93von_Mises_criterion) and log likelihood estimates.

Once you've picked the functional form of the distribution, parameter values are usually estimated by [maximum likelihood estimators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) or [method of moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_%28statistics%29).

If you're planning on using the results in a simulation of some sort, you might consider just bootstrapping your sample rather than distribution fitting. Yet another option if simulating would be to run a designed experiment where you vary the distribution choice and see if alternatives have a significant impact on your results before worrying too much about fitting just the right distribution.

Comment: HI pjs, i just looked over your answer above. I trying to simulate a set of process of which i have a large data sets. In a simulation, I would like to recreate data of the process in the simulation environment. I thought distribution fitting  and finding the parameters would be the solutions, so that i could take sample of a distribution for each process in the simulation. Do you have any literature on why to use bootstrapping instead of distribution fitting. I am fairly new to this subject so please excuse me if the question is "stupid"

Comment: @Uis234 Not really a suitable topic for a comment thread here.  Quick response would be to suggest you look up the input modeling section of any reputable simulation text book, such as Chapter 9 of [Banks, Carson, Nelson, & Nicol](https://www.pearsonhighered.com/program/Banks-Discrete-Event-System-Simulation-5th-Edition/PGM130682.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617333/how-to-fit-the-best-probability-distribution-model-to-my-data-in-python/64572402#64572402) can help.

I presented an example of how to find the best distribution according to BIC criterium using [OpenTURNS](http://openturns.org).

You define a list 'Distribution Factories' `tested_distributions = [ot.WeibullMaxFactory(), ot.NormalFactory(), ot.UniformFactory()]`

then you call `BestModelBIC` to find the best fitting
`best_model, best_bic = ot.FittingTest.BestModelBIC(sample, tested_distributions)`

Currently, you can choose among 30 available 'Factories' in OpenTURNS (see below). TruncatedNormalFactory is available but not yet TruncatedBetaFactory

```
print(ot.DistributionFactory.GetContinuousUniVariateFactories())

[Out]: 
[ArcsineFactory,
BetaFactory, 
BurrFactory, 
ChiFactory, 
ChiSquareFactory, 
DirichletFactory,
ExponentialFactory,
FisherSnedecorFactory,
FrechetFactory,
GammaFactory,
GeneralizedParetoFactory,
GumbelFactory,HistogramFactory,
InverseNormalFactory,
LaplaceFactory,LogisticFactory,
LogNormalFactory,
LogUniformFactory,
MeixnerDistributionFactory,
NormalFactory,
ParetoFactory,
RayleighFactory,
RiceFactory,
StudentFactory,
TrapezoidalFactory,
TriangularFactory,
TruncatedNormalFactory,
UniformFactory,
WeibullMaxFactory,
WeibullMinFactory]
#30
```

Answer (score 0):

The `distfit` library can all the points you are asking for. It searches across 89 theoretical distributions to find the best with the loc, scale arg parameters.
Example:

***I need to do data fitting to find the distribution of a given data.***

```
pip install distfit

from distfit import distfit
import numpy as np

# Create dataset
X = np.random.normal(0, 2, 1000)

# Default method is parametric.
dfit = distfit(distr='popular') # 'all' for all 89 or specify your own list.
# Search for best theoretical fit on your empirical data
results = dfit.fit_transform(X)

# [distfit] >INFO> fit
# [distfit] >INFO> transform
# [distfit] >INFO> [norm      ] [0.00 sec] [RSS: 0.00221125] [loc=0.002 scale=1.902]
# [distfit] >INFO> [expon     ] [0.00 sec] [RSS: 0.189094] [loc=-5.527 scale=5.529]
# [distfit] >INFO> [pareto    ] [0.00 sec] [RSS: 0.189094] [loc=-536870917.527 scale=536870912.000]
# [distfit] >INFO> [dweibull  ] [0.03 sec] [RSS: 0.00285214] [loc=0.005 scale=1.667]
# [distfit] >INFO> [t         ] [0.18 sec] [RSS: 0.00221128] [loc=0.002 scale=1.902]
# [distfit] >INFO> [genextreme] [0.08 sec] [RSS: 0.00295224] [loc=-0.699 scale=1.892]
# [distfit] >INFO> [gamma     ] [0.02 sec] [RSS: 0.00221712] [loc=-2156.094 scale=0.002]
# [distfit] >INFO> [lognorm   ] [0.13 sec] [RSS: 0.00235342] [loc=-149.018 scale=149.010]
# [distfit] >INFO> [beta      ] [0.03 sec] [RSS: 0.00208639] [loc=-11.915 scale=24.259]
# [distfit] >INFO> [uniform   ] [0.00 sec] [RSS: 0.122291] [loc=-5.527 scale=11.639]
# [distfit] >INFO> [loggamma  ] [0.06 sec] [RSS: 0.00209695] [loc=-376.616 scale=55.771]
# [distfit] >INFO> Compute confidence intervals [parametric]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 10))
dfit.plot(chart='PDF', ax=ax[0])
dfit.plot(chart='CDF', ax=ax[1])
```

[image: PDF/CDF plot]

The best fit can be found in the results which will answer this question:

***I need to find the pdf function of the distribution.***

```
print(results['model'])

{'distr': <scipy.stats._continuous_distns.beta_gen at 0x155d67e35b0>,
 'stats': 'RSS',
 'params': (19.490647075756037,
  20.18413144061353,
  -11.915134641255602,
  24.25907054997436),
 'name': 'beta',
 'model': <scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_continuous_frozen at 0x15583c00760>,
 'score': 0.002086393123419647,
 'loc': -11.915134641255602,
 'scale': 24.25907054997436,
 'arg': (19.490647075756037, 20.18413144061353),
 'CII_min_alpha': -3.124111310171669,
 'CII_max_alpha': 3.141196658807374}
```

***But, how to find the parameters of the distribution ?***

```
results['model']['params']
```

***What if the data cannot fit the truncated gamma well ?***

```
# Take one of the other fitting models.
results['summary'][['distr', 'score']]

# Plot results
dfit.plot_summary()
```

[image: Fit results]

***The QQ-plot (qunatile-quantile) show that it is not a good fit for truncated gamma.***

```
# Make qqplot for the best fit.
dfit.qqplot(X)
```

[image: QQplot]

```
# Inspect all other fits
dfit.qqplot(X, n_top=10)
```

[image: QQplot other fits]

***If data fitting cannot work here, what other methods I can use for that ?***

You can use non-parametric methods:

```
# Quantile method
dfit = distfit(method='quantile')

# Percentile method
dfit = distfit(method='percentile')
```

***Any help would be appreciated.***

*Disclaimer: I am also the author of this repo.*