# How to adjust mathematical function to data?

Tags: python, statistics, distribution

I'm currently doing some research work that produces a lot of data. Some of my results' distributions appear to be very similar to log-normal. I would like to somehow verify this hypothesis. Things that are not clear to me are:

1) How can I check the distribution automatically in Python? My goal is to confirm log-normal distribution or find another distribution that might better fit the data.

2) How can I get the distribution parameters that are determinatd by my results?

Comment: Automatically ? I don't think the singularity exists yet. Going the semi-automatic route, have you looked at numpy ?

Comment: put your data into [this](http://zunzun.com/StatisticalDistributions/1/)

Comment: Do the fitting and estimation tasks _have_ to be done in Python? If not, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425475/how-to-do-data-fitting-to-find-the-distribution-of-given-data may be of interest to you.