# How to fit the best probability distribution model to my data in python?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, simulation, distribution

i have about 20,000 rows of data like this,,

```
Id | value
1    30
2    3
3    22
..
n    27
```

I did statistics to my data,, the average value 33.85, median 30.99, min 2.8, max 206, 95% confidence interval 0.21.. So most values around 33, and there are some outliers (a little).. So it seems like a distribution with long tail.

I am new to both distribution and python,, i tried class fitter https://pypi.org/project/fitter/ to try many distribution from Scipy package,, and loglaplace distribution showed the lowest error (although not quiet understand it).

I read almost all questions in this thread and i concluded two approaches (1) fitting a distribution model and then in my simulation i draw random values (2) compute the frequency of different groups of values,, but this solution will not have a value more than 206 for example.

Having my data which is values (number), what is the best approach to fit a distribution to my data in python as in my simulation i need to draw numbers. The random numbers must have same pattern as my data. Also i need to validate the model is well presenting my data by drawing my data and the model curve.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to select the best model according to the Bayesian information criterion (called BIC).
OpenTURNS implements an automatic method of selection ([see doc here](http://openturns.github.io/openturns/latest/user_manual/_generated/openturns.FittingTest_BestModelBIC.html)).

Suppose you have an array `x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`, here a quick example:

```
import openturns as ot
# Define x as a Sample object. It is a sample of size 11 and dimension 1
sample = ot.Sample([[xi] for xi in x])

# define distributions you want to test on the sample
tested_distributions = [ot.WeibullMaxFactory(), ot.NormalFactory(), ot.UniformFactory()]

# find the best distribution according to BIC and print its parameters
best_model, best_bic = ot.FittingTest.BestModelBIC(sample, tested_distributions)
print(best_model)
>>> Uniform(a = -0.769231, b = 10.7692)
```

Comment: You may use `GetContinuousUniVariateFactories` to create the list of all univariate factories, but this may return the `Histogram` distribution. This may be disappointing in some cases.